# Using New-AzSqlDatabaseExport with SAS token

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I am trying to export Azure SQL DB as a bacpac file into storage account. I am making use of `AzSqlDatabaseExport` pwshell module to achieve this. The script works if I use Storage access key, however the script does not work when I use a SAS token and change the `StorageKeyType` to `SharedAccessKey`. Can anyone please help me understand if this module even accepts a SAS key as input.

```
Param (
    [string][Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $AdminPassword
)

Process {
    $AdminSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString –String $AdminPassword –AsPlainText -Force
    $Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "storageaccount" -Environment 'AzureCloud' -SasToken '?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-11-23T18:11:49Z&st=2023-11-23T10:11:49Z&sip=49.200.220.5&spr=https&sig=i68D3IxhabcdxyzfHoMIHuQ2DBvgRzc42UXFisKdf2PJoSQ%3D'
    $container=Get-AzStorageContainer -Name 'sqlblobtest' -Context $Context
    $storageURI=$container.CloudBlobContainer.Uri.OriginalString+"/sqlagent.bacpac"
    $exportRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName 'TEST-AZURE-RG'  -ServerName 'test-azure-sql' -DatabaseName 'Customers' -StorageKeytype 'SharedAccessKey' -StorageKey '?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-11-23T18:11:49Z&st=2023-11-23T10:11:49Z&sip=49.200.220.5&spr=https&sig=i68D3IxhabcdxyzfHoMIHuQ2DBvgRzc42UXFisKdf2PJoSQ%3D' -StorageUri 'https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/' -AdministratorLogin 'testadmin' -AdministratorLoginPassword $AdminSecurePassword
    Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationStatusLink $exportRequest.OperationStatusLink
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to export a bacpac file of a database to a storage account using SAS key authentication:

```
Import-Module Az.Sql
Import-Module Az.Storage
$AdminPassword=ConvertTo-SecureString –String "<password>"  –AsPlainText -Force
New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName "<resourceGroupName>" -ServerName "<serverName>" -DatabaseName "<databaseName>" -StorageKeyType "SharedAccessKey " -StorageKey "<SASKey>" -StorageUri "https://<storageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/db.bacpac" -AdministratorLogin "<admin>" -AdministratorLoginPassword $AdminPassword
```

[image]

This will create a bacpac file of the database as shown below:

[image]